# Insert multiple rows with single a query from one table into another in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-insert, unique-constraint, ora-00001

I have two tables, dcr_details_new and dcr_details_old where the primary key is DCRDID.

[image]

Both dcr_details_new and dcr_details_old tables share the same structure.The primary key is DCRDID where I increment by one in each insert.

I need to fetch all the rows from dcr_details_old into dcr_details_new where I have to filter the records by DOCREGNO and DCR_No

So a normal single row import/insert is running exactly as follows.

```
INSERT INTO dcr_details_new 
SELECT (select Max(DCRDID) + 1 from dcr_details_new),
       TWNCODE,
       '100008',
       DOCCATOGARY,
       DCR_NO,
       VISIT_NO,
       GIVEAWAY,
       COMPETITORBRN,
       REMARK,
       DCRDRDATE,
       COM_ACTI
 FROM dcr_details_old  
WHERE DOCREGNO= 'T10037'
  and DCR_NO = 28766;

1 rows created.
```

Now I want to skip filtering by `dcr_no` and insert the records as it contain too many records with different `dcr_no`'s. Here when I filter only with  `DOCREGNO` the select statements returns many records and when I try to loop the and insert I always mess up with the primary key as it is not incrementing as I wish.

Here is the loop I have tried and the error I'm getting.

```
declare
  i integer := 1;
BEGIN 
  FOR x IN (select * from dcr_details_old  WHERE DOCREGNO= 'T10037')
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO dcr_details_new (DCRDID, TWNCODE, DOCREGNO, DOCCATOGARY,
                                 DCR_NO, VISIT_NO, GIVEAWAY, COMPETITORBRN,
                                 REMARK, DCRDRDATE, COM_ACTI)
    SELECT (select Max(DCRDID) + 1 from dcr_details_new),
           TWNCODE,
           '100008',
           DOCCATOGARY,
           DCR_NO, VISIT_NO, GIVEAWAY, COMPETITORBRN,
           REMARK, DCRDRDATE, COM_ACTI
      FROM dcr_details_old;

     i := i + 1;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

**Error:**

```
**ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYS_C0061873) violated
ORA-06512: at line 5**
```

In this error `SYS_C0061873` is the primary key `DCRDID`.
Here in insert the value `'100008'` is the new `docregno` I have to put manually.

Any simple way to proceed? Kindly seek your assistance.

Comment: Do not try to calculate the PK id by yourself/inside sql. Add a trigger  to your database, which generates this value on every insert.

Comment: Thanks  Terradon. But with the situation I cant modify the existing database

Comment: how are the PK values generated in the existing database?

Comment: I'm sure that the PK is generated by a sequence, you need find it and reuse. example: 'INSERT INTO suppliers
(supplier_id, supplier_name)
VALUES
(supplier_seq.NEXTVAL, 'Kraft Foods');' see more info here [link](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/sequences.php)

Comment: select Max(DCRDID)+1 from dcr_details_new

Comment: that is whati meant with a trigger, this trigger generates the PK using a sequence, on every insert, but he can't add that.

Comment: You are exactly right.But any ideas without modifying the table?I am not allowed to amend.

Comment: You are trying to insert the PK, leave that one out of your SQL and it probably will be generated by a sequence automatically?

Comment: @Terradon There is no trigger nor a sequence. They select the highest current ID and just append 1 and use that as an ID. As stated in his post

Comment: ok, split your problem:  check with a simple sql: select Max(DCRDID)+1, which value you get returned. If this is a valid value =>, select all fields from first table, except the PK, then create  the insert sql for the second table, you have a right PK by now. This method is not resource efficient, I am sure a rwal DBA cold make an efficient sql for this,but it should work?

Comment: I came now with this idea: can you use "rownum + max(pk_id_of_the_dest_table)" to get the offset?

Comment: Thanks all .. I got the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert all records from **OLD** table to the **new** table with new primary keys use following statement.

Note that the key part is to get the maximal existing key and increates it using **ROWNUM**.
For a signle migration step (i.e. no parallel migration and the application is down) this is a secure way.

```
 INSERT INTO dcr_details_new
 (DCRDID,TWNCODE,DOCREGNO,DOCCATOGARY,DCR_NO,VISIT_NO,GIVEAWAY,
 COMPETITORBRN,REMARK,DCRDRDATE,COM_ACTI)
 select 
  (select max(DCRDID) from dcr_details_new) + rownum as DCRDID,
  TWNCODE,DOCREGNO,DOCCATOGARY,DCR_NO,VISIT_NO,GIVEAWAY,
  COMPETITORBRN,REMARK,DCRDRDATE,COM_ACTI
 from dcr_details_old where DOCREGNO = 'T10037'
 ;
```

Comment: Thanks ... I ll send u a Marmite :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that this variant is right for you.

```
declare
 v_DCRDI number;
begin
select Max(DCRDID)+1 into v_DCRDI from dcr_details_new;
INSERT INTO dcr_details_new 
SELECT v_DCRDI+rownum DCRDI, TWNCODE,'100008',DOCCATOGARY,
DCR_NO,VISIT_NO,GIVEAWAY,COMPETITORBRN,REMARK,DCRDRDATE,COM_ACTI
FROM dcr_details_old  
WHERE DOCREGNO= 'T10037' /*and DCR_NO = 28766*/;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure all you're after is a single insert statement along the lines of:

```
INSERT INTO dcr_details_new (dcrdid,
                             twncode,
                             docregno,
                             doccatogary,
                             dcr_no,
                             visit_no,
                             giveaway,
                             competitorbrn,
                             remark,
                             dcrdrdate,
                             com_acti)
  SELECT (SELECT MAX(dcrdid) FROM dcr_details_new) + rownum,
         twncode,
         '100008',
         doccatogary,
         dcr_no,
         visit_no,
         giveaway,
         competitorbrn,
         remark,
         dcrdrdate,
         com_acti
  FROM   dcr_details_old;
```

Using "max(val) + some_val" to generate new primary key values is, in general, a bad idea. If this is a static data table that is only ever inserted into by release scripts, then it's just about acceptable. Personally, I'd still rather use a sequence!

I would highly recommend that you create a sequence that has a starting value of the current max val + 1 (or some other value), and then use `new_seq.nextval` when adding rows into the table. Much simpler, and way more foolproof!

Comment: Here I found we have to declare the increment 

select max(DCRDID) from dcr_details_new) + ***** rownum as DCRDID ****


Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

After all your help this is the final answer worked for me.

```
INSERT INTO dcr_details_new
(DCRDID,TWNCODE,DOCREGNO,DOCCATOGARY,DCR_NO,VISIT_NO,GIVEAWAY,
COMPETITORBRN,REMARK,DCRDRDATE,COM_ACTI)
select 
(select max(DCRDID) from dcr_details_new) + rownum as DCRDID,
TWNCODE,'100008',DOCCATOGARY,DCR_NO,VISIT_NO,GIVEAWAY,
COMPETITORBRN,REMARK,DCRDRDATE,COM_ACTI
from dcr_details_old where DOCREGNO = 'T10037' ;
```

Thanks everybody